# DataFrame in jupyter notebook does not sort in output/ DataFrame does not show content in output but is sorted however

Tags: python, database, mongodb, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Good day,

I have the following problem with my code in jupyter notebook:

```
[In(1)]'from IPython.display import display
print ("DataFrame")
display(foodItems_df)'

[Out(1)]'DataFrame
0   5e3e96b51c9d44000010a5a8    apple       A   E   B   AA
1   5e494e3b1c9d44000053a8fe    banana      A   E   B   AA
2   5e494e4a1c9d44000053a8ff    pineapple   A   E   B   AA'
```

//(The output shows a grey-white table but this cannot be seen on stackoverflow) This code does not sort the output dataframe

```
[In(2)]'foodItems_df = json_normalize(list(db.foodItems.find()))
foodItems_df.sorted = sorted(foodItems_df)
foodItems_df.sorted'
[Out(2)]'['_id', 'a', 'aa', 'b', 'e', 'itemName']'
```

//This code however sorts the output data but it is lacking the database/ dataframe content(apple, banana, pineapple...)

There are imports of mongodb etc... that i did not copied here as an part of my code.

Is there a way to combine those two codes in any way so that they makes an output that sorts the whole database(headlines and content)?

I appreciate for any help/ advice for this problem.

UPDATE:

[UPDATE image of jupyter notebook(sorting works but the content is a bit different(not sorted))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbryN.png)

Comment: `foodItems_df.columns = sorted(foodItems_df)` now print `foodItems_df`

Comment: @Sayandip Dutta Thank you. I tried it and it works^^. I appreciate your help. However if i print() it it works. When i use display() it doesn't work. Am i doing anything wrong?:/